# Refreshing the source code without refreshing the web page

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping, cookies

I want to measure the number of cookies regarding of the policie accepted by the user.
So, for example, one the website https://sephora.fr i'm first accessing to the control panel :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)  
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(website)  
driver.find_element_by_id('footer_tc_privacy_button').click()
```

Then i would like to click on the black button ("Enregistrer")

```
driver.find_element_by_id('save-consent').click()
```

The problem is that the HTML code source is updated after the first click and selenium keep the initial source code -> selenium can't find the button 'save-content'.
Unfortunately i can't refresh the page because it will close the control panel.

I tried to sleep some seconds after the first click, but it's not working.

Any idea ?

**Edit : i also tried to switch to the Iframe**

```
 frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//frame[@name="privacy-iframe"]')
 driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

because the button Enregistrer is on this iframe

```
<iframe id="privacy-iframe" class="tc-reset-css tc-privacy-center-iframe" src="https://cdn.trustcommander.net/privacy-center/default/modern/index.html" title="Vos paramètres cookies" lang="fr"></iframe>
```

but it's not also not working

**EDIT : Solution**

I switched to the iframe

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_id('privacy-iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
driver.find_element_by_id('save-consent').click()
```

then i switched back to the parent

```
driver._switch_to.parent_frame()
```

Comment: Can you share HTML of `Enregistrer` element ? Sleep will not work since it will stop the thread execution not the web page API's call

Comment: <button type="button" id="save-consent" aria-label="Enregistrer la configuration des cookies" class="btn save"> Enregistrer </button>

Answer (score 1):

I do not see the name in the iframe tag attribute shared by OP :

try with ID instead :

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_id('privacy-iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```